# Glyphicon icon does not appear

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

Here I have tried to use icon in two ways. I am facing issue with 2nd method. Class name is currect even why it does not display the icon?

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/vCUC5/2/)

html:

```
    <!-- Glyphicon in a H1 tag -->
    <h1>Hello, <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span> !</h1>

<ul>
<li class="glyphicons glyphicon-globe"><a href="hashtag.html?lang=en"><i></i><span>Hashtag tracking</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to correct spelling for second one remove `s` for `glyphicons glyphicon-globe`

Here is updated [code](http://jsfiddle.net/vCUC5/3/)

Answer (score 0):

in the `<li>` Tag you written glyphicons instead of glyphicon.

So here is the corrected one:

[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/vCUC5/5/)

html:`

```
 <!-- Glyphicon in a H1 tag -->
 <h1>Hello, <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span> !</h1>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="hashtag.html?lang=en"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></i>
 <span>Hashtag  tracking</span></a></li>
 </ul>`
```